# xauth: error while loading shared libraries:

Tags: linux

Following is my Linux version:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago) , 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
I want to configure vncserver .When I do "vncserver" and press enter I get following errors:

```
xauth: error while loading shared libraries: libXmuu.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

WARNING: The first attempt to start Xvnc failed, possibly because the font
catalog is not properly configured.  Attempting to determine an appropriate
font path for this system and restart Xvnc using that font path ...
Could not start Xvnc.

/usr/bin/Xvnc: error while loading shared libraries: libXdmcp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/Xvnc: error while loading shared libraries: libXdmcp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Following rpms are installed in my Linux machine for vnc:
 rpm -qa | grep vnc

```
tigervnc-1.1.0-16.el6.centos.x86_64
tigervnc-server-1.1.0-16.el6.centos.x86_64
```

How the above errors can be fixed? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

---

libXdmcp.so.6 : `# yum install libXdmcp`

---

Please use the `yum provides` command to decide package names, like :

```
# yum provides */libXdmcp.so.6
```

---